# Convert textbox.text to float

Tags: c#, winforms

```
    private void tbnRaknaMoms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ToPercentage().ToString());
    }
    public float ToPercentage()
    {
        float varde = float.Parse(tbxInput.Text);
        float result = 100 * varde;
        return result;
    }
```

I want to make a method that counts the tax. When I run this I get an error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll.

Comment: Try `float.Parse(tbxInput.Text, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);` or `float.Parse(tbxInput.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Wow your right. I was trying to input 0.2 in textbox but i guess i have to use decimal for that right?

Comment: You want to validate input before you start trying to parse it (or use TryParse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the input is parsed according to the CultureInfo of the local computer. If you want to have the same "default" decimal delimiter, use this:

```
 float value = float.Parse(tbxInput.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: It says the CultureInfo does not exits in current context.

Comment: @AlexanderHalef add the missing using `System.Globalization` as the compile error says.

Comment: @AlexanderHalef @Matyas is correct, I didn't specify the `using` statement for `CultureInfo`